# Replace selected drop down list option with corresponding code onEdit at Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a file with several worksheets. In the "J4:BA1000" of some of these sheets are drop down options where the user can select letters from A to I. What I'm trying to achieve is that upon selection, the selected option is replaced by its corresponding code: 1 to 9. With this, I tried out the code below, which is also something I saw from stack overflow. However, it's not working and I'm not sure why. I believe the logic is correct, the sheet names are exact and the conditions are there.

Likewise, I believe there's an improvement on how I do the checking of sheet names to avoid the multiple || (or), and as well the changing of values to avoid the multiple ifs.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getName();
  var range = e.getRange;
  var targetrange = ss.getRange("J4:BA1000");
  var cell = range.getValue();
  
  if ( sheetName == "Kalos" || sheetName == "Logos" || sheetName == "Atos" || sheetName == "Manos" || sheetName == "Sodos" || sheetName == "Antos" || sheetName == "Minos" || sheetName == "Ambos" ) {
    if (Checkkk(targetrange,range)){
      if(cell == 'A'){range.setValue("1");}
      if(cell == 'B'){range.setValue("2");}
      if(cell == 'C'){range.setValue("3");}
      if(cell == 'D'){range.setValue("4");}
      if(cell == 'E'){range.setValue("5");}
      if(cell == 'F'){range.setValue("6");}
      if(cell == 'G'){range.setValue("7");}
      if(cell == 'H'){range.setValue("8");}
      if(cell == 'I'){range.setValue("9");}
    }
  }
}
  
function Checkkk(R1, R2) {

  var LR1 = R1.getLastRow();
  var Ro2 = R2.getRow();
  if (LR1 < Ro2) return false;


  var LR2 = R2.getLastRow();
  var Ro1 = R1.getRow();
  if (LR2 < Ro1) return false;

  var LC1 = R1.getLastColumn();
  var C2 = R2.getColumn();
  if (LC1 < C2) return false;

  var LC2 = R2.getLastColumn();
  var C1 = R1.getColumn();
  if (LC2 < C1) return false;

return true;

}
```

So just to explain the logic, when I perform an edit, it checks if the edited cell is within the several sheets inf the first IF. If `TRUE`, it then checks using the `Checkkk` function if the edited cell is within J4:BA1000. If `TRUE`, it then checks if the selected value is within A to I. If `TRUE` it replaces that letter with its corresponding code, which is from 1 to 9. Again, I think the code is logically correct; I'm just not sure where's the mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*To get the range of an event object you need to use `e.range`, not `e.getRange`.*

#### Code:

I also changed your initial Sheet name checking condition to make it slightly more efficient, and removed the need for multiple ifs in the block by changing subsequent `if` blocks to `else if`s:

```js
function onEdit(e) {  
  var sheetNames = ["Kalos", "Logos", "Atos", "Manos", "Sodos", "Antos", "Minos", "Ambos"];
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getName();
  
  if (!(sheetNames.indexOf(sheetName) > -1)) {
    return;
  }
    
  var range = e.range;
  var targetrange = ss.getRange("J4:BA1000");
  var cell = range.getValue();
  
  if (Checkkk(targetrange, range)){
    if(cell == 'A'){range.setValue("1");}
    else if(cell == 'B'){range.setValue("2");}
    else if(cell == 'C'){range.setValue("3");}
    else if(cell == 'D'){range.setValue("4");}
    else if(cell == 'E'){range.setValue("5");}
    else if(cell == 'F'){range.setValue("6");}
    else if(cell == 'G'){range.setValue("7");}
    else if(cell == 'H'){range.setValue("8");}
    else if(cell == 'I'){range.setValue("9");}
  }
}
```

I didn't change your `Checkkk` function at all.

#### References:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually initially used the e.range, but then experimented with the e.getRange. I forgot to revert to that eventually. Will try out your edited code. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to run the function using the run button first so you can authorise the app to use the Spreadsheet service before `onEdit()` can work!

Comment: How can I try to trigger the user to allow the code to use the spreadsheet without telling them to run it in the app script interface itself? I saw somewhere how to do this but I can't seem to find it anymore. :)